# MediaWiki API: How to get an article's list of editors

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia-api

As part of the [WP:ASE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aASE) project, I want to get the list of editors that have edited a given article.

For instance, for the article [Szklarka Mielęcka](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Szklarka_Miel%C4%99cka) ([history](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Szklarka_Miel%C4%99cka&action=history)) that would be:
`Kotbot, AnomieBOT, Xenobot`

I could not find anything in the [MediaWiki API](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMeta).

Any better idea than scraping the history web page?
Downloading the [history data dumps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aDatabase_download#English-language_Wikipedia) is not a solution because I don't have the resources to handle 5 terabytes of text.

Scale: I want to do this on about 1000 random articles, twice a year.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found:

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Sinjhoro&rvprop=user&rvlimit=500